# Is it possible to reach the grey cloud?

Tags: one-single-life-2

In the credits' stage where you have to jump from an orange cloud to a grey one. Is it possible to reach it?

[image: One Single Life jump]

Comment: Blargh, I should know this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No but the secret cloud is right under the orange cloud. When I got there I hit the edge of the orange cloud and fell on the secret island.

Comment: Great answer! I'll also add the spoiler tag.